# change color of particular <td> element dynamically in angular 2

Tags: angular

I m creating an angular 2 app where I do have a table in which I want to change the background color of the  element dynamically.

```
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let i of rows">
<td>blank</td>
<td [style.color]="color">data</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

what I want is to change the color of 5th row to green, 6th row to red.
Selection of which rwo to change color would be dynamic.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can provide what you tried so far and we can help if needed

Comment: Look for "Local variables" in this tutorial: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

Comment: @mickdev this is the code i tried: [style.color]="i == 2 ? 'red' : 'green'"... 
This workd but cant get it work dynamically.

Comment: @ssougnez Thanks for your help, I get it done statically but can't get it dynamically

Comment: ok, you should edit your question to include what you tried. That said, how do you determine which row must be green or red ? what are the criteria ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of tries I got that done.

I have edited this line...

```
<td [style.background-color]="i == rowNum ? 'red' : 'green'" ></td>
```

And the rowNum is generated by ramdon function Math.random().

Comment: This will make every row either red or green, I assumed you wanted to leave other rows alone

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what "dynamic" means in this case (defined in the code, the user needs to choose it, etc...). In any case, I think this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/dIhoU1AbtD2SmEKjNkgX could give you a first idea on how to achieve that.

The idea is to define the color of the row based on their index in a literal object:

```
private styles = { 4: "red", 5: "green" };
```

Answer (score 1):

stylesheet: (you used `color` so I did too, but you mentioned `background-color`, so consider changing?)

```
td.red-row {
    color: red;
}

td.green-row {
    color: red;
}
```

template:

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let i of rows; let j = index;">
        <td>blank</td>
        <td [class.red-row]="j == redIndex"
            [class.green-row]="j == greenIndex">data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

component:

```
private greenIndex: number = 4;
private redIndex: number = 5;
```

This way you can set `greenIndex` and `redIndex` to whatever you want whenever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let i of rows; ; let x = index"> 
<td>blank</td>
<td [ngClass]="{colorGreen: x == 4, colorRed: x == 5}">data</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

NOTE: let x = index allows you to check the index of iteration... 
Because index counts from 0 then x==4 will be your 5th element and x==5 will be your 6th... 
colorGreen - class for your green color, colorRed - class for red color.

Hope this helps